# WPF: Custom style for TabControl and TabITem - how to make the tab header collapse if all tabs are collapsed

Tags: wpf

I've been making a custom style for TabControls and TabItems for a program I'm designing, and would like to know if it's possible to have it so that if **all** TabItems in a TabControl have the property `Visibility="Collapsed"`, the TabControl's TabPanel (where the tabs are displayed) can be collapsed or otherwise completely hidden. This is of course a default behaviour in TabControls, but since they're using a custom style (so they are no longer fugly, and are consistent with the theme of the application) this behaviour seems to have disappeared (likely because as of now I have the Height property set to a hardcoded value)... which brings me to my next point, the height of the TabPanel - when tabs are visible - should be several pixels more than the height of the tabs. Of course this makes using margins difficult, because that extra height should be removed if all TabItems are collapsed.

So to summarize, what I'm looking to do:

- TabControl when **any** tabs are not collapsed:

  - TabPanel has a height of 26px (taller than the TabItems, which are 18px tall)
- TabControl when **all** tabs are collapsed:

  - TabPanel is completely collpased/hidden, with zero height

Many thanks to any of you awesome people that can help me out. I've been working with WPF consecutively for long enough to fry my brain, and a simple solution to this problem escapes me *(I need a break!)*

Answer (score 0):

Well nevermind!
This is what happens when you've spent too long working on stuff.

The solution was to give the TabItems a margin that gives the extra height above them, and then to set the TabPanel's Height property to Auto inside the TabControl's ControlTemplate. Duh!